# ImageMagick not working on windows server

Tags: c#, web-applications, imagemagick, windows-server-2008-r2

I have created a web application in c# for `converting PDF to JPG` using `ImageMagick` through command line.

This works fine in local but when I have uploaded it on server it was not working.

```
public string appPath = "C:\\Program Files\\ImageMagick-6.5.3-Q16"; 

Process myProcess = new Process();
myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = appPath + @"\convert";
myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = (@"-type truecolor -quality " + tbQuality.Text + " -colorspace " + cbColourSpace.SelectedValue.ToString().ToLower() + " -density " + tbDPI.Text + @" " + currentFile + resizeString + @" " + outputFile);
myProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
myProcess.Start();
myProcess.WaitForExit();
```

This runs successfully without any exception but not generating any `JPG`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Imagemagick requires you to install ghostscript.

It's required by ImageMagick to interpret Postscript and PDF.
```

Now it works fine on any system.